# updating dataset inside a local package

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, package, local

I am building a local package that constantly uses the same dataset for comparisons with the input data. The package will be shared with other people, meaning the dataset should be installed along with the package (Like the datasets in sci-kit learn datasets). The problem is that the dataset needs to be updated every month and I am not sure how to update a dataset inside a package that is already installed. Any ideas? Here is and skeleton of my code/pseudocode for the package.

```
class myClass():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.dataset = dataset in the package
        self.input = pd.DataFrame()
        self.output = pd.DataFrame()
    def somefuntion(self):
        self.check_date_dataset()
        if checked_date < Today - 30 days:
            self.update_dataset()
        do_something_with_self.input()
    def check_date(self):
        checks date of dataset in day and returns the age
    def update_dateset(self)
        update the data set in the package  # (IS THIS POSSIBLE)?
```

Is it possible to update a dataset inside an already installed package?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [uszipcode](https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/) package.
It maintains an up-to-date cache in the users's home directory (outside the package dir), downloading a fresh copy as needed.
You may wish to adopt a similar approach.